# input one text from document.write();

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have one javascript file which has a different text in `document.write();`,
like:

```
document.write('here 1 line of text');

document.write('here 2 line of text');
```

and I add a script file on my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsfile.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to load one line of text instead of all text from this js file?
For example I need to load from the .js file only the first line of text `'here 1 line of text'`.

Comment: Remove the other line?

Comment: not without modifying that file.

Comment: no, I need to have 1 js file but execute text from it optionaly for different cases, to not to create many different .js files with one document.write(); function

Comment: Write a function or if else statements.

Comment: Here's one idea: store your lines in their own `.txt` files (or a database) and use AJAX to load the one(s) you want.